# I'm getting an error in disabling the component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting error 'Assets\ExplosionGun.cs(17,34): error CS1026: ) expected'. I've been trying for a long time, but haven't been able to find a solution. I am using Visual Studio and the Unity Engine.

My Code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class ExplosionGun : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject explosion; 
    public Camera cam;   
    
    public float force = 100000000000000000f;
    public float radius = 10000f;

    public TimeManager timeManager;

    void Update()
    {

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1");
           shoot();
           this.enabled = true;

    }
            
    void shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit _hitInfo;
        // If we hit something
        if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out _hitInfo))
        {
            // Create an explosion at the impact point
            Instantiate(explosion, _hitInfo.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(_hitInfo.normal));

            timeManager.DoSlowmotion(); 

            Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(_hitInfo.point, radius);

            foreach (Collider nearbyObject in colliders)
            {
                Rigidbody rb = nearbyObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                if (rb != null)
                {
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point, radius);
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(force, _hitInfo.point * 1000, radius);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not getting an error in disabling anything ... this is a compier error telling you that you have a syntax error somewhere: `if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1");` should rather be `if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))` ... also you should wrap the two lines below in `{ }` otherwise the `if` only refers to the first line and `this.enabled = true` will be executed **always** ... Also: the `this.enabled` makes absolutely no sense anyway ... if `Update` is called it means this component already **is** enabled .. otherwise it won't be called at all so trying to enable it within `Update` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1");
   shoot();
   this.enabled = true;
```

That if has no closing `)`. It should be:

```
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
   shoot();
   this.enabled = true;
}
```

Notice how I replaced your `;` with brackets to make sure the following code is inside of the if-Block.

The error `Assets\ExplosionGun.cs(17,34): error CS1026: ) expected` exactly told you what you need to do. You should look into C# errors and how to read and understand them properly.

Comment: MATE THANK YOU SO MUCH YOU ARE SO GOOD THAT WAS SO FAST THANK YOU

Comment: @lakshya'Coding'Jain I'm glad I was able to help you. In case you are new to StackOverflow: You can mark this answer as accepted so your question is officially answered.

Comment: Note that the `this.enabled = true;` doesn't make any sense anyway! Either the component is already enabled .. or `Update` would never be called so trying to enable this component from within `Update` makes absolutely no sense